# how to attach an event to dojox.mobile.heading 'back' button

Tags: dojo, dojox.mobile

In addition to the 'back' button functioning as expected, I need to asynchronously invoke a function to update some db tables and refresh the UI.

Prior to making this post, I did some research and tried the following on this...

```
<h1 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" id="hdgSettings" data-dojo-props="label:'Settings',back:'Done',moveTo:'svStart',fixed:'top'"></h1>

dojo.connect(dijit.registry.byId("hdgSettings"), "onclick",   
    function() {
        if (gblLoggerOn) WL.Logger.debug(">> hdgSettings(onclick) fired...");
        loadTopLvlStats();
});
```

Since my heading doesn't have any other widgets than the 'back' button, I thought that attaching this event to it would solve my problem... it did nothing.  So I changed it to this...

```
dojo.connect(dijit.registry.byId("hdgSettings")._body, "onclick",   
    function() {
        if (gblLoggerOn) WL.Logger.debug(">> hdgSettings(onclick) fired...");
        loadTopLvlStats();
});
```

As it turns out, the '._body' attribute must be shared by the Accordion widget that I just happen to use as my app's main UI component, and any attempt to interact w the Accordion rendered my entire app useless.

As a last resort, I guess I could simply forgo using the built-in 'back' button, and simply place my own tabBarButton on the heading to control my app's transition and event processing.

If the community suggests that I use my own tabBarButton, then so be it, however there has to be a way to cleanly attach an event to the built-in 'back' button support.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
var backButton = dijit.registry.byId("hdgSettings").backButton;
if (backButton) {
  dojo.connect(backButton, "onClick", function() { ... });
}
```

Remarks:

- The code above should be executed via a dojo/ready call, to avoid using dijit's widget registry before it gets filled. See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/ready.html.
- Note the capitalization of the event name: "onClick" (not "onclick").
- Not knowing what Dojo version you use (please always include the Dojo version information when asking questions), I kept your pre-AMD syntax, which is not recommended with recent Dojo versions (1.8, 1.9). See http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/modern_dojo/ for details.

Comment: Thank you Adrian, it works flawlessly in dojo 1.9, and will test it in dojo 1.8 very soon as my project may have to drop back to 1.8 due to other issues not related to this question.